# Safari Cuts text of a button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

On safari browser I have this problem:
[image: buttons]

I tried `overflow: visible;` but it didn't help, I'm using bootstrap css class on this buttons:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="float-left">
                    <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive brand" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOG OUT</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Return To Dashboard</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Try to reduce left/right padding on button.

Comment: Didn't help....

Comment: We cannot know exactly what the problem is only by looking at the button. Providing more context and ideally a code snippet will allow us helping you  with your issue.

Comment: Updated code, sorry can't make code snippet

Comment: @Popeye I updated your post, moving your code block into a snippet and adding in the Bootstrap CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your container isn't large enough for your buttons. You have two options:

### Change your `button` classes

Currently you're using `col-xs-6`, which is 50% width for each column. Yet you have some space in the first column you could give your second column. See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="float-left">
                    <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive brand" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-2">
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-4"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOG OUT</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-8"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Return To Dashboard</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</header>
```

### Change your `table` width to 100%

As Awadhesh mentioned, you should make your `table` element 100% width. Though using tables for layout should be avoided if possible.

```css
table { width: 100% }
```

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <header>
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="float-left">
                        <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive brand" />
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <div class="row">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOG OUT</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-xs-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Return To Dashboard</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="float-left"><a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive brand"> </a></td>
            <td><br>
              <br>
              <br>
              <div class="btn-group">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOG OUT</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Return To Dashboard</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. Get rid of your tables. Bootstrap does layout for you so they're not needed.
2. Don't use `<br>` for spacing. Use padding or margin
3. change `col-xs-6` to `col-md-6`

The following HTML works:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
     <div class="container-fluid">

                <a href="#"> <img class="img-responsive brand" />
                </a>

                <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-md-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LOG OUT</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link col-md-6"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Return To Dashboard</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

     </div>
</header>
```

A live example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fescjgwm/2/